# yarn install/add does not install full packages

Tags: yarnpkg

In my React application, using `yarn add <package>` or `yarn install` does not install full packages.

Here I'm trying to install `@elastic/eui`, and most of the components are not present in node_modules. Successive attempts made it weirder, for yarn installed random components from one attempt to another, but the package is not fully installed at any point.

I've try to `yarn cache clean` and `yarn install --check-files` without success.

What could cause this issue?